# create array of array with date and week in angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to create an array of array with date regroup by 7 seven for each week. Something like

```
full_dates = [
[{date: 'Mon 12', date: 'Tue 13, date: 'Wed 14'}],
[{date: 'Mon 19', date: 'Tue 20, date: 'Wed 21'}],
and so on
];
```

so what I did to begin it create an array of all the date I need, giving a start and stop.

Then, I'd like to loop in this value and each time in the loop that i%7 is equal to 0, I change week and try to save it in another array in my "big array".

so I did something like that.

```
// initialize full_calendar
full_calendar: any[] = [[]];

...

// create an array of date between an initial date and a final date
let initialTime = new Date("2020-10-12Z08:00:00");
let endTime     = new Date("2020-10-27Z08:00:00");

for (let q = initialTime; q <= endTime; q.setDate(q.getDate() + 1)) {
  this.dates.push(q.toString());
}
console.log(this.dates);

// make a loop for each date, and regroup them by 7 for a week 
let week = -1;
for (let i = 0; i<14;i++) {
  if (i%7 == 0) {
    week += 1;
  }
this.full_calendar[week].push({date:this.dates[i]});

}
console.log(this.full_calendar);
```

But I got error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

It looks, like I cannot create new array inside array. MAybe I should make another initialization ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need small changes in your code

```
full_calendar: any[][] = [];

...

let week = 0; // Week needs to start from 0
for (let i = 0; i < 14; i++) { // Instead of 14, it might be difference between start and end date
  if (i % 7 == 0 && i !== 0) {
    week += 1;
  }
  // As you initialized `full_calendar` as an empty array, you need to do undefined check
  if (this.full_calendar[week]) {
    this.full_calendar[week].push({
      date: this.dates[i]
    });
  } else {
    this.full_calendar[week] = [{
      date: this.dates[i]
    }];
  }
}
```

Comment: @Yann92 Glad to hear it helped ;)